# Возможно ли так настроить DNS сервер?

Tags: dns

Добрый день.
Предположим, имеется VPN-канал для доступа к определённым ресурсам, недоступным из интернета, у этих ресурсов имеются свои доменные имена, и находятся они в частных подсетях. Эти доменные имена обслуживает удалённый DNS-сервер. Трафик до остальных ресурсов идёт напрямую без VPN.

Вопрос: Возможно ли сделать DNS-сервер, который будет кэшировать определённые домены с dns-сервера из vpn (например 10.0.0.1), а остальные кэшировать, например, с 8.8.8.8 и при недоступности днс 10.0.0.1 запретить резолвить их с 8.8.8.8?

И подскажите, пожалуйста, на каком софте это можно реализовать? djbdns/bind/unbound/что-то еще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать в bind, описав нужный домен к конфиге с типом forward:

```
zone "domain.name" IN {
        type forward;
        forward only;
        forwarders { 10.0.0.1; };
};
```

Так же обратите внимание на TTL в описании тех доменов. ваш bind будет кешировать ответы от 10.0.0.1 и при потери связи с ним продолжит отвечать закешированными записями до истечения их TTL. По истечении этого времени или если запись ранее не кешировалась, а 10.0.0.1 не доступен, будет возвращать ошибку NXDOMAIN.